# Isn't putting questions on hold similar to putting freedom of speech on hold?

Tags: discussion

If you think a question is too broad or too complicated, you can comment on it and mention these points, however, by putting a question on hold you are eliminating the probability that someone might be interested in answering such broad questions in perhaps a clever way.

Given that this question isn't put on hold, my question is why eliminate the chance of someone coming up with very clever answers for difficult or broad questions?

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1357/).

Comment: I think it plausible that, in many cases, putting a question on hold here is an act of mercy for those too fragile to handle genuine free speech.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If you think a question is too broad or too complicated, you can comment on it and mention these points,

Normally we do. Supposing this is [personal experience here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226129/), you *were* told why it was too broad.

> however, by putting a question on hold you are eliminating the probability that someone might be interested in answering such broad questions in perhaps a clever way.

Yes, preventing an answer is exactly the point of closing such questions. The reasons for that [can be found on the Help Center page on closed questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

> my question is why eliminate the chance of someone coming up with very clever answers for difficult or broad questions?

Not every question posed on this site is acceptable, we have limits on what types of questions we want here; see [this Help Center page on acceptable questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [this Help Center page on unacceptable questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

---

*If* you feel your question was inappropriately closed, the *proper* action is to post a question on this Meta site asking *Why was my question closed?* with an explanation as to why you think it was wrongly closed and should be [reopened](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) (please read this link carefully). Asking the question you have here doesn't help you any (as you can see by all the downvotes on your question and answer), as the old adage goes [*you catch more flies with honey than vinegar*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can_catch_more_flies_with_honey_than_with_vinegar).

Comment: I'm curious to understand what is to be disagreed with in this answer.

Answer (score 10):

No several different ways.

- Stack Exchange is not a government, and doesn't have the power to keep you from saying anything, so there is no issue of censorship even possible. Go forth and say what you want certain that Stack Overflow won't stop you.
- Freedom of speech does not imply that you have the freedom of someone else's channel with which to promote that speech. You can say what you want with your own resources, but you are not entitled to those of Stack Overflow unless they want to let you use them.
- Freedom of speech has never guaranteed an audience. You don't get to force anyone to listen to your political manifest and you don't get to force anyone to read your questions.
- This is a community and it has mores and traditions that have been developed by the users over time. These include limitations on what belongs here. You don't wander into someone club house and demand that they listen to you orate.

Comment: Stack Overflow?

Comment: @JohnDuffield: dmckee was around when it was *just* SO and not "the SE network" that it is now.

Comment: Also, the company that runs all this is (currently) officially called "Stack Overflow", no longer "Stack Exchange".

Comment: Ouch. I have to say though that I don't like this: _"Stack Exchange is not a government, and doesn't have the power to keep you from saying anything, so there is no issue of censorship even possible"_. On that basis you could claim there's no censorship in physics at all. And I'm afraid I really don't agree. I know physicists who can't get their papers into a journal or even onto the arXiv, and they really aren't quacks peddling nonsense.